# I-765: most recent passport, vs passport used on last arrival?

Tags: usa, immigration

When filling out the I-765, it says under,

> Information About Your Last Arrival in the United States

There is a prompt for,

> 21.b. Passport Number of Your Most Recently Issued Passport

Obviously that should be the most recently issued passport, but what about

> 21.e. Expiration Date for Passport or Travel Document

should that be the most recently issued Passport, or the one you used on your last arrival in the USA?